# The picturebox be hidden during execute a long loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I'm showing a picture box contains gif photo during executing my code:

```
Me.PicLoading.Visible = True
Call xCLS.MyCodes_GetID("tbl_cities", Me.t1)
Me.PicLoading.Visible = False
```

and that's working very well but when I use the long procedure with long "For Loop", the PictureBox box becomes hidden, and after the loop is executed the image box becomes visible.
this problem is happening with the loop only.

the next code is the loop:

```
Public Sub MyCodes_GetID(ByVal TblName As String, ByVal TxT As TextBox)
    Dim xCount, i As Integer
    Dim xDtCount As DataTable = New DataTable()

    MyCodes_Fill_DataTable("Select ID From " & TblName & " Order By ID", xDtCount)
    xCount = Convert.ToInt32(xDtCount.Rows.Count)

    For i = 1 To xCount
        Dim xCountID As Byte
        Dim xDtCountID As DataTable = New DataTable()
        MyCodes_Fill_DataTable("Select ID From " & TblName & " Where ID = " & i & "", xDtCountID)
        xCountID = Convert.ToInt32(xDtCountID.Rows.Count)
        If xCountID = 0 Then
            GoTo Line1
        End If
    Next
Line1:
        TxT.Text = CStr(i)
    End Sub
```

any comments

Comment: In the loop, you are not doing anything to the picture box. And you should probably replace that `GoTo` statement with `Exit For`.

Comment: @preciousbetine I know that and I tried `Exit For` and I got the same result

Comment: @preciousbetine  I set the Image directly from the Properties not by code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI thread is too busy processing your code to display the `PictureBox`. You'd need to call its `Refresh` method before doing the work to force it to be repainted first.

Your GIF will not animate for the same reason. Do long-running tasks asynchronously. If you don't know how, it's time to learn. That's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Judging from the GOTO statement, I'd say that now would be a great time for the OP to look into building .NET specific VB code.